# How Should I integrate Amazon RDS in Flutter? Any native dart support package?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dart, flutter, aws-sdk, grpc

how to use AWS RDS in flutter dart code?

I went through - [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=865155)
It says -

> I work on the AWS SDK team. I am not aware of any plans to support Flutter at this point. I will take this to my team as a feature request and will post back

[Should I do as suggested here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415178/flutter-connecting-to-a-database-in-server)

> Build your own service layer using HTTP, gRPC that talks to some backend service that provides access to a data store. You can do this with Express, Rails, CloudFunctions, etc.

Comment: Yes, I would roll your own. There's typically some docs for http, curl etc, that can be used. Especially if you don't need that many features for your app, it "may" not be too tricky.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use dart code to do HTTP/gRPC, or use [Platform channel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to wrap dart code around native iOS and Android code of AWS official SDK.

On another note, I'm highly concerned when you connect directly from mobile (Flutter) to database (AWS RDS). Please be aware that anything on mobile app can be reversed engineer, and your database connection credential is not safe. It's recommended to have only backend proxy, or at least severless (such as AWS lambda function) connect directly to database (not mobile or web frontend). The only exception is with [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) because it has seamless integration with Firebase Authentication