# How would I make Flutter connection with Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, flutter, flutter-web

I want to make a simple web page using flutter as flutter for web, but I want to use Oracle as database in the backend. I know firebase will be more helpful, but Its my course project and I'm supposed to use oracle at back with anything in the front.

So, is there any way I can connect flutter to oracle and can perform simple function of adding items in table, deleting and updating

Comment: Please see a similar discussion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415178/flutter-connecting-to-a-database-in-server

Comment: You may have forgotten that "Dart is a client-optimized language for fast apps on any platform". https://dart.dev

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about building a flutter desktop app that connects to an oracle db.  I am going to build a dotnet core web api that handles all the db connection/commands and have the flutter app use the web api with getx.